# Load, Import or Include Local HTML file into an HTML file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way that we can include an HTML file into another HTML file with jQuery or Javascript? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [jQuery `.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/). To load `import.html` into another file, just use:

```
$("#myElement").load("import.html");
```

Comment: This method require Ajax right?

Comment: yes, you use it uses jQuery's ajax